# How to I list applications sorted by modified time in Finder on OS X 10.8?

Tags: macos, finder, applications

I discovered that on 10.8 the Applications folder does not allow you to change the sort order, it's always listed by name.

How can I change the sort order?

[image]

Comment: That’s strange… I can change the sort order in my Applications folder. Is the name column header highlighted with blue?

Comment: @DeepanshuUtkarsh I added a screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

The view your screenshot displays can be produced if you go to the **View** menu and select **Arrange by ▸ Name** (or press <kbd>^</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>). When "Arrange by Name" is selected, indeed changing the sort order is not possible. If, however, you select **View** then **Arrange by ▸ None** or press <kbd>^</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>, your problem is solved.

Comment: none of these options worked for me. I can arrange folders opened independently but if I am trying to place or open a file the menu is still unusable. I also do not have an "Arrange By" item, it is "Sort by" and it doesn't work for opening/placing files. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

On the top of the Finder window, you have a set of buttons called View. Right beside that is a button called Arrange with a drop down arrow. Click the arrow and you can arrange however you want: by name, date, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Go to View Menu > Arrange By > None. That will make the columns editable. You can sort by whatever criteria you want now.