# OSX 10.8.5 file picker dialog doesn't allow sort by column

Tags: macos, ui, dialog, finder

First post to this site and I'm writing with a user gripe.  I haven't found any reference to this issue after some searching.

I have a MacBook Air with OSX 10.8.5 and I've noticed a new behavior.  When I use the file picker dialog in certain apps (uploading a file in Safari or locating a lost file in iTunes; Command-O in Safari is the easiest way to replicate; some apps are fine -- opening or Save-As in Microsoft OFfice does not have this issue) with the view set to "List", the columns ("Name", "Date Modified", etc.) show as a translucent bar on top, and I can't click on the column labels to sort.  Instead there is a weird behavior where clicking on the column label header will actually "click through" to the underlying, barely visible, file listed on top.

In short, when I upload a file in Safari, I can't sort the list of files by name or any other criteria, and I'm stuck on reverse-alphabetical sort in every folder for some reason.  Seems like a definite bug vice a feature, and it's happening in at least two apps.

Any one else know what I'm talking about?  Sorry if the description is unclear.

Thanks for any assistance. This is really bugging me.

Best,

Jim

Comment: not really a programming question, maybe this would fit better on ask different.

Comment: Your answer is here:

http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/61641/how-to-i-list-applications-sorted-by-modified-time-in-finder-on-os-x-10-8